# Can I use twinaxial cable while still on the spool?

Tags: inductor, transmission-line, inductance

I have 500ft of shielded twinaxial cable (belden 9463) on a spool and need to do a distance test on a product I'm developing. Is it worth unraveling the spool to get rid of any EMI from my spool of wire, since it is essentially a giant inductor.

Comment: I'm assuming this is _sheilded_ twinax?  Could you _edit your question_ to clarify this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cable is shielded, it should make no difference whether you keep it on the spool or unwind it and lay it out flat.

And its properties are determined by the spacing between the conductors; the dielectric, and the spacing between the conductors and the shield.

Finally, like any shielded cable product, you want to make sure you terminate the shields properly on both ends.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran some tests with the cable still on the spool and didn't have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it worth unraveling the spool to get rid of any EMI from my spool
> of wire, since it is essentially a giant inductor.*

It's not a giant inductor because you have forward and return wires essentially occupying the same space. Look up bifilar wound resistors; they have low inductance due to the way they are wired: -

[image]

Image from [Wirewound Resistor](https://electronicsreference.com/types-of-resistors/wirewound-resistor/)